# Display all the records instead of related record in a visual force page

Tags: soql, relationships

I have a custom object as " gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c " it has a look up relation with "product" object and api name is give as "gmod__Product__c".

1)Im querying on "gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c " object to retrive the related records ,but it displays all the records on gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c in Visual force page.

```
list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select
                                                    id,
                                                    Name,
                                                    gmod__Product__c,
                                                    gmod__Quantity__c,
                                                    gmod__Price__c ,
                                                    gmod__Month__c,
                                                    gmod__date__c,
                                                    gmod__Quarter__c,
                                                    gmod__Amount__c ,
                                                    Actual_Price__c,
                                                    gmod__Year__c,
                                                    gmod__Month_Text__c,
                                                    Forecast_Date__c,
                                                    gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c.gmod__Product__r.Name
                                                    from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c ];
```

I shall appreciate your help.

Comment: There is no where condition on your query so it will return all records.

Comment: @BarCotter:I tried using different ways of query ,but still it does not display the related record.[SELECT Id, Name,gmod__product__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c where createddate != null order by name Asc],[SELECT Id, gmod__product__r.name ,createdby.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c where gmod__product__r.name like '%BX%'].Is that im doing any blunt mistake in the query.Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Which `gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c` record do you want to display in the page?

Comment: @BarCotter:The product details which got displayed on "Opportunity" object visual force page ,the same product details should get displayed on custom visual force page on "Quote "object in gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c section.The issue is when i query on gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c ,it doesnot retrieve the correct related record from the product.Instead it displays all the records of gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c.

Comment: That is because you are not doing a where clause on `gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c` e.g. `select Id from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c where Id = :ofId`.

Comment: @BarCotter:I tried with the ids in query.It does not displays any record.I have different query on different objects .gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c e.g. select Id from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c where Id = :qId.It doesnot display any record.q is a variable for quote object.similarly tried for an opportunity object as gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c e.g. select Id from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c where Id = :opportunity.Id.throws an Error as Invalid bind expression type of Schema.SObjectField for column of type Id.Variable does not exist: opflistId

Answer (score 0):

You should add a WHERE conditon on Query like .. WHERE gmod__Product__c ! = NULL

So that it will return records which has related gmod__Product__c

Comment: :I tried the where condition but still it displays all the records of gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c in visual force page.If i use WHERE gmod__Product__c ! = NULL order by name limit 1,it displays the unrelated record of the gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c .